# Can I play Gonti, Lord of Luxury's exiled card after he leaves the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm interested in using [Gonti, Lord of Luxury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGonti%2c%20Lord%20of%20Luxury%5d) as my commander. If I summon him and exiled a card with him, and then he leaves the battlefield (is destroyed, exiled, etc), can I still cast that exiled card? Can I do it if he then returns to the battlefield again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"*For as long as that card remains exiled, you may look at it, you may cast it, and you may spend mana as though it were mana of any type to cast it.*" creates a continuous effect that affects players or the rules of the game.

> 611.2a A continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability lasts as long as stated by the spell or ability creating it (such as “until end of turn”). If no duration is stated, it lasts until the end of the game.

The effects lasts for the specified duration ("*For as long as that card remains exiled*"). Period. It is of no consequence if the source of the ability that's the source of the effect (Gonti) ceases to exist (changes zone)<sup>[1]</sup>. This is confirmed by the following ruling:

> You may look at and cast that card (and spend mana as though it were mana of any type to do so) even if Gonti leaves the battlefield. If another player gains control of Gonti, that player can’t look at or cast the card, and you still can.

Don't confuse this with a continuous effect created by a static ability (e.g. [Glorious Anthem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlorious%20Anthem%5d)).

> 611.3b [A continuous effect generated by the static ability of an object] applies at all times that the permanent generating it is on the battlefield or the object generating it is in the appropriate zone.

---

1. If anything requires information about the source of the ability that's the source of the effect, Last Known Information will be used.

Answer (score 8):

As said on [Gonti, Lord of Luxury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGonti%2c%20Lord%20of%20Luxury%5d) 's gatherer page :

> You may look at and cast that card (and spend mana as though it were mana of any type to do so) even if Gonti leaves the battlefield. If another player gains control of Gonti, that player can’t look at or cast the card, and you still can.

If it comes back to the battlefield later, it'll be a completely different object, and won't affect the first card exiled, you'll still be able to cast it.

Comment: Sounds paradox, do you have the rules, that he is able to cast the first card?

Comment: It's not that _he_ is able to cast the first card. _You_ are able to cast the first card. And the rule is right there on the Gatherer page. That is an official ruling.

Comment: "For as long as that card remains exiled, you may look at it, you may cast it, and you may spend mana as though it were mana of any type to cast it."

The ability isn't dependent on Gonti being in game or not.

Comment: @Ydrasaal That kind of thing can seem counterintuitive since it looks a little bit like a static ability type of thing, and we all know those only work while the creature is on the battlefield. :) Takes some proficiency to understand it's a perpetually granted condition.

Comment: Recommend clarifying the last sentence, explicitly referencing Gonti and highlighting that every time his effect works every time he enters the battlefield. Casting a second Gonti, with one in play, will put another condition on the stack, prior to State based Actions. Flickering Gonti is an amusing strategy.

Comment: @doppelgreener, Re "*it looks a little bit like a static ability type of thing*", That's because it is. Both static abilities and this triggered ability create a continuous effect. The difference is that continuous effects from static abilities end with the source, while continuous effects from spells and abilities last indefinitely or for a specified duration.